# PhpStrom7 SFTP Connection failed

Tags: java, ide, synchronization, sftp, phpstorm

I have some troubles with deployment project configuration in PhpStorm7.0 (I have the same problem in IDE WebStrom)

When I trying to connect through **ftp** - everything fine.

But if choice **sftp** - I have this error:

> Test SFTP Connection
>
> Connection to 'echuvelev.ihc.ru'
>
> Java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Logs:

```
    2014-08-19 14:06:29,038 [  73753]   WARN - loyment.ui.WebServerConfigForm - Could not connect to SFTP server at "sftp://echuvelev.ihc.ru/". 
org.apache.commons.vfs2.FileSystemException: Could not connect to SFTP server at "sftp://echuvelev.ihc.ru/".
    at org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.sftp.SftpFileProvider.doCreateFileSystem(SftpFileProvider.java:108)
    at org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.AbstractOriginatingFileProvider.getFileSystem(AbstractOriginatingFileProvider.java:102)
    at org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.AbstractOriginatingFileProvider.findFile(AbstractOriginatingFileProvider.java:80)
    at org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.AbstractOriginatingFileProvider.findFile(AbstractOriginatingFileProvider.java:64)
    at org.apache.commons.vfs2.impl.DefaultFileSystemManager.resolveFile(DefaultFileSystemManager.java:698)
    at org.apache.commons.vfs2.impl.DefaultFileSystemManager.resolveFile(DefaultFileSystemManager.java:624)
    at com.jetbrains.plugins.webDeployment.connections.RemoteConnectionPool.createConnection(RemoteConnectionPool.java:139)
    at com.jetbrains.plugins.webDeployment.connections.RemoteConnectionManager.openConnection(RemoteConnectionManager.java:103)
    at com.jetbrains.plugins.webDeployment.PublishUtils$1$1.run(PublishUtils.java:115)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$8.run(ApplicationImpl.java:420)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:439)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:695)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$1$1.run(ApplicationImpl.java:150)
Caused by: org.apache.commons.vfs2.FileSystemException: Error during processing known-hosts file "/Users/echuvelev/.ssh/known_hosts".
    at org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.sftp.SftpClientFactory.createConnection(SftpClientFactory.java:126)
    at org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.sftp.SftpFileProvider.doCreateFileSystem(SftpFileProvider.java:97)
    ... 16 more
Caused by: com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 403
    at com.jcraft.jsch.KnownHosts.setKnownHosts(KnownHosts.java:235)
    at com.jcraft.jsch.KnownHosts.setKnownHosts(KnownHosts.java:60)
    at com.jcraft.jsch.JSch.setKnownHosts(JSch.java:299)
    at org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.sftp.SftpClientFactory.createConnection(SftpClientFactory.java:122)
    ... 17 more
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 403
    at com.jcraft.jsch.Util.fromBase64(Util.java:53)
    at com.jcraft.jsch.KnownHosts.setKnownHosts(KnownHosts.java:221)
    ... 20 more
```

I tried reinstall all IDE (with removing cache, setting in Library dir), but it doesn't help me.

Any ideas?

p.s ssh work fine with this server in console, i have this problem only in IDE, and only with sftp protocol.

Comment: ) IDE version? 2) Anything interesting in logs (Help | Show Log in..)? 3) And if detailed SFTP logging is enabled? http://devnet.jetbrains.com/docs/DOC-1202

Comment: Thanks, LazyOne for your comment, I resolved my issue by this ticket http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-12925#comment=27-580440
I had the same problem with known_hosts file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found solution in this ticket [youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-12925#comment=27-580440](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-12925#comment=27-580440) 
It's the same problem with known_hosts file.

**Solution:**
Try to backup and remove .ssh/known_hosts file, and recreate it adding hosts when needed.

Comment: Thank you! JFTR: I've opened Settings > Languages & Frameworks > PHP. And then I clicked on the folder icon next to "Path mappings" > folder icon text to Remote Path. At this moment, Phpstorm tries to connect to a remote path and recreate the known_hosts file. Moreover, worth remembering: double-check the password entered in Settings > Languages & Frameworks > PHP > CLI Interpreter.